# Oracle Cumulative Calculation using Windows Analytical functions

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to Windows functions (lag, lead etc) and I am using Oracle. I did some research and tried few solutions but I couldnt get the desired result.
I have an inventory table, where I want to find out the items used and the remaining item left on the given day.

The data comes in as follows

```
Dates     | Items | Total_Inv_Items | Damaged_Items | Sellable_Items | Sold_Items | Remaining_Items
11/13/2020  Pen       999             15                 984             109        875
11/13/2020  Book      401             6                  386             109        277
11/14/2020  Pen       0               0                  0               121        0
11/14/2020  Book      0               0                  0               121        0
11/15/2020  Pen       0               0                  0               31         0
11/15/2020  Book      0               0                  0               31         0
11/16/2020  Pen       201             3                  198             33         165
11/16/2020  Book      301             5                  296             33         263
```

Useable_Items and Remaing_Items are caluclated columns.
**Sellable_Items** = Total_Inv_Items - Damaged_Items
**Remaning_Items** = Sellable_Items - Sold_Items
**Total_Inv_Items** is manufacture or new items available in the store.

The desired output:

```
Dates     | Items | Total_Inv_Items | Damaged_Items | Sellable_Items | Sold_Items | Remaining_Items
11/13/2020  Pen       999             15                 984             109        875
11/13/2020  Book      401             6                  386             109        277
11/14/2020  Pen       0               0                  875             121        754
11/14/2020  Book      0               0                  277             121        156
11/15/2020  Pen       0               0                  754             31         721
11/15/2020  Book      0               0                  156             31         125
11/16/2020  Pen       201             3                  919             33         886
11/16/2020  Book      301             5                  421             33         388
```

The remanining item is cummulative and the sellable items changes whenever there is a new item added to the inventory or it is same as previous days remaining item.

**Query that gives me first data**

```
SELECT
    Date, 
    Items,
    NVL(Total_Inv_Items, 0) as Total_Inv_Items,
    NVL(Round(Total_Inv_Items * DamagePercentage/100), 0) as Damaged_Item,
    Round(Total_Inv_Items - (Total_Inv_Items * DamagePercentage/100)) as Sellable_Items,
    Sold_Items,
    Round(Total_Inv_Items - (Total_Inv_Items * DamagePercentage/100))- Sold_Items as Remaining_Items
FROM      
    Table
Order By
Date
```

Note:
If you notice on Nov 16th there was new items that was available in the store so it adds to the previous days remaining items(Ex Pen 201-3+721).

Comment: If you can share the query you have so far, that would be helpful for review and debugging.

Comment: @etch_45 I updated my questin with the query

Comment: @Nik . . . Why are you using `SELECT DISTINCT`?  It suggests that you have duplicates in your data -- and in fact something wrong with the data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff my bad I dint notice it, I confirm there is no duplicates, I had to edit the query to change it to my test data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Gordon Linoff and @Tejash, your comments helped me to resolve this issue. The following code gave me the desired result.
NOTE: **1.5** is the pecentage of Damaged Items which I have included it directly in the query, most of the time its comes from the DB.

```
SELECT
Dates,Items,
Total_Inv_Items,
Damaged_Item,
CASE 
    WHEN Total_Inv_Items = 0 THEN LAG(Remaining_Items) OVER (partition by items order by dates)
    ELSE Sellable_Items+NVL(LAG(Remaining_Items) OVER (partition by items order by dates),0)
END as Sellable_Items,
Sold_Items,
Remaining_Items
FROM
(
SELECT
Dates,Items,
Total_Inv_Items,
Damaged_Item,
Sellable_Items,
Sold_Items,
SUM(Sellable_Items - Sold_Items) OVER (partition by items order by dates) as Remaining_Items
FROM
(
SELECT
    Dates, 
    Items,
    NVL(Total_Inv_Items, 0) as Total_Inv_Items,
    NVL(Round(Total_Inv_Items * 1.5/100), 0) as Damaged_Item,
    Round(Total_Inv_Items - (Total_Inv_Items * 1.5/100)) as Sellable_Items,
    Sold_Items,
    Round(Total_Inv_Items - (Total_Inv_Items * 1.5/100))- Sold_Items as Remaining_Items
FROM
Table T
) A 
)B
Order By
Dates
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lag function as follows:

```
SELECT Date, 
    Items,
    Total_Inv_Items,
    Damaged_Item,
    -- FOLLOWING IS CALCULATED EXPRESSION BASED ON YOUR FORMULA: Pen 201-3+721
    Total_Inv_Items 
    - Damaged_Item 
    + COALESCE(LAG(Remaining_Items) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEMS ORDER BY DATE),0) AS Sellable_Items,
    -- EXPRESSION ENDS HERE
    Sold_Items,
    Remaining_Items
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT
    Date, 
    Items,
    NVL(Total_Inv_Items, 0) as Total_Inv_Items,
    NVL(Round(Total_Inv_Items * DamagePercentage/100), 0) as Damaged_Item,
    Round(Total_Inv_Items - (Total_Inv_Items * DamagePercentage/100)) as Sellable_Items,
    Sold_Items,
    Round(Total_Inv_Items - (Total_Inv_Items * DamagePercentage/100))- Sold_Items as Remaining_Items
FROM Table)
Order By Date
```

This expression should be placed in the outer query. The inner query should be your query which is giving the first data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried and it is giving me wrong output.

Comment: Thanks, I understood the changes you had done above, but my question is, the "reamianing items" columns is not cumulative. If I run the query for eg on Nov 16th I get (201 - 3 + 0(Nov 15th remaining Items) = 198 -- still the same as my data set) it is not using 721 because remaining item is not being cumulative.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you just want cumulative sums and arithmetic:

```
select t.*,
       sum(total_inv_items - damaged_items) over (partition by item order by date) as sellable_items,
       sum(total_inv_items - damaged_items - sold_items) over (partition by item order by date) as remaining_items   
from t
order by date;
```

Comment: Thanks, Am i missing something in the above query, there is 2 select and it throwing me an error when I tried to implement the above query and yes you are right I want the cumulative of remaining so that the remaining items of previous day are available in the store to sell it on next day.